# How to Get a String Value From Column Table?

Tags: laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm having trouble getting the information I need. In the database, I have tables: users, students, and teachers. In the 'users' table, it has a column that is called 'status' that specifies if the user is a teacher or a student. I can't seem to be able to extract that specific information to check if its a student or a teacher.

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't been working?

Comment: Please, add your actual code to see where is the problem

Comment: Got it! Just need to add the Auth::user()->user_status == ' student' into a if to verify. Thank you all for your quick anwser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.

So you have two user types, a common user table, and a table for each user type.

At first I'ld say that instead of using a boolean to discriminate between the two user types, I'ld use relations for that.

In your `User` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher', 'user_id');
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'user_id');
    }

    ...
}
```

This way you can then easily check if your user is a teacher or student by checking the existence of a relation:

```
$isStudent = is_null($user->student);
$isTeacher = is_null($user->teacher);
```

If you want to retrieve all the User models that are teachers or students you can instead:

```
$areStudents = \App\User::has('student')->get();
$areTeachers = \App\User::has('teacher')->get();
```

I hope this will help you.

P.S.: I based my answer on the details you put in your question, I hope I didn't misunderstood it. If you need more specific answer try to publish your code too.